# Angular 2 - How to change the interval of an RxJS Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I'm using rxJS Observable Interval to refresh the data being fetched. I can't figure out the way to change the interval setting. I've seen something about using the Subject class provided by rxJS but I can't manage to get it to work.

I provided an simplified example in this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q95dkt)

In the AppComponent I have this method.

```
getTime() {
        this.timeService.getTime(this.refreshInterval)
          .subscribe(t => {
            this.currentTime = t;
            console.log('Refresh interval is: ' + this.refreshInterval);
          }
        );
}
```

And in the service component I currently have this code.

```
getTime(refreshInterval: number) {
  return Observable.interval(refreshInterval)
        .startWith(0)
        .map((res: any) => this.getDate())
        .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

Can someone perhaps provide me with a working example it would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your plnkr, your goal is to allow user to modify timer intervals.

You expect, that change of refreshInterval will change declared stream of rxJs:

```
    this.timeService.getTime(this.refreshInterval)
      .subscribe(t => {
        this.currentTime = t;
        console.log('Refresh interval is: ' + this.refreshInterval);
      }
    );
```

and this is wrong.

every time, you update refreshInterval, you need to:

- unsubscribe or destroy previous stream.
- create new stream and
  subscribe again

Comment: Actuallly, this answer may be inaccurate. I was able to accomplish the stated goal without destroying and recreating streams after struggling with this for a while myself

Answer (score 9):

You do not need to destroy and recreate the entire Observable stream to change the `refreshInterval`. You only need to renew the part of the stream that depends on the changing interval.

First simplify your service's `getTime()` so it's not in charge of determining the frequency of outputs. All it does is return the time:

```
getTime() { return (new Date()).toString(); }
```

Now the calling code will determine the schedule.  Just 3 simple steps:

**1.** A source function that adjusts to the desired interval:

```
/** Observable waits for the current interval, then emits once */
refreshObs() {return Observable.timer(this.refreshInterval)}
```

**2.** An observable chain that uses the [`repeat` operator](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/repeat.md) to continuously re-execute the stream:

```
getTime$ = Observable.of(null)
            .switchMap(e=>this.refreshObs()) // wait for interval, then emit
            .map(() => this.timeService.getTime()) // get new time
            .repeat(); // start over
```

**3.** A subscription to trigger the whole thing:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.getTime$.subscribe(t => {
        this.currentTime = t;
        console.log('refresh interval = '+this.refreshInterval);
    });
}
```

This works because `refreshObs()` returns a new observable each time the stream is repeated, and that new observable will wait according to the currently set interval before emitting.

[**Live demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/4eMhUXjn1t98dvRbQI56?p=preview)

Comment: One major caveat with the code, when I reduce the interval I expect it to run again with the new value and repeat with the shorter interval. In your demo if set the interval to 10minutes and then set it to 1sec I have to wait 10minutes to see the update.

Comment: Hi @Arvand The code behaves as the OP described.  The indicated interval is respected, and only then does the next interval take effect.  If you wish for the change in delay to immediately cancel the currently running interval and supercede it with a new one, it can be done but you're then asking for something different.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to build on the previous answers here (and elsewhere on Stack Overflow). My example has a common `RefreshService` that various components can use for subscriptions. This way, a site can have a single "Refresh every X seconds" component that each component can subscribe to.

https://plnkr.co/edit/960yztjl3dqXQD2XPSei?p=preview

The service provides the function `withRefresh` that provides an `Observable`. It takes advantage of `BehaviorSubject`, which will immediately trigger an event on the subscription.

```
export class RefreshService {

  static interval$: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(30000);

  setInterval(newInterval: number){
    RefreshService.interval$.next(newInterval);
  }

  public withRefresh() {
    return RefreshService.interval$
      .switchMap((int: number) => Observable
        .interval(int)
        .startWith(0)
      );
  }
}
```

Then any component can use this service as follows:

```
this.refreshService
  .withRefresh()
  .switchMap(() => /* do something on each interval of the timer */);
```

Comment: great answer! but why did you need two switchMaps?